# Can we write REPLACE function in WHERE clause in sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table `payments` with a column `loanId` with the following sample values

[image]

I need to execute a select query and search by `loanId`, but the issue is that the search term does not have the hyphens `-`. For example, the API gets the `loanId` as `59112710` or `34559348841`. For this, I have written the following query that works.

```
select * from "payments" where REPLACE("loanId", '-', '') = '59112710';
```

I am using sequelize and wanted to know if I'll have to run it as a raw query or is it possible to write it in sequelize syntax?

Comment: Why not just write a test case?

Comment: @Belayer not sure what you mean by test case?